# Extending ArrayList and referring to a deserialized object in the constructor

Tags: java, this

I have a class called Library that extends ArrayList. I did this because (I think) a true is-a relationship exists between the Library class and an ArrayList - a Library is simply a collection of books, plus a few methods.

One of those methods is load(), which deserializes a saved Library object. My question is: How do I make the deserialized object into the "active" instance of Library? I want to do something like `this = load()` in the constructor of the library, since `load()` returns a Library object. However, I get a compiler error `cannot assign a value to final variable this` when I try to do it. What is the proper syntax to use for this purpose?

```
public class Library extends ArrayList<Book> implements Serializable{

public Library(){
    load();
}
...

Library load() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    File f = new File (System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Documents\\CardCat\\library.ser");   
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream (f));   
    Library lib = (Library)ois.readObject();
    System.out.println("ran load sucessfully");
    return lib;
}
```

EDIT: It seems that the universal consensus is that this is the wrong approach, and that I should instead create a Library class that doesn't extend ArrayList, but has an ArrayList instance variable. This is actually how I had it structured about an hour ago, but I thought that extending ArrayList might be a little simpler. My primary rationale for this was that the ArrayList was the only variable of the Library class, I refer to that ArrayList very frequently from other classes, and every time I did so I was having to call `library.libList`, so I thought being able to refer simply to `library` would be simpler. Looking back, and taking your input into consideration, it seems this this is a rather trivial benefit and it comes at the cost of a significant hit to performance.

Although I'd like to better understand what those costs are, am I understanding your thoughts correctly? I am (obviously, I'm sure) still learning and experimenting with all sorts of things, and very much appreciate any input that helps me identify failed experiments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can't overwrite `this` by design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979623/why-is-assignment-to-this-not-allowed-in-java).

Some things to consider:

- Why is a Library an ArrayList? Is there any case where you need your Library to be assignable to an ArrayList? Is there any reason that a Library *must* be a List and backed by an array? Implementing `Collection` may be reasonable, but forces you to implement methods that might not make sense in your design.
- If a Library isn't an ArrayList, then you can use [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), which is easier to use anyway. Just have a member variable which is an ArrayList (or any kind of collection).
- For deserialization, you usually use a static function or a factory, not the constructor. See other answers for how to do this.

---

To clarify my comments below with code, here's an example of adding the books as an instance variable, then creating whatever methods are necessary to access them from the outside:

```
class Library {
    private final Collection<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        this.books.add(book);
    }

    public Collection<Book> getAllBooks() {
        ...
    }

    public Book getBookByTitle(String title) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Deleting my answer in favor of this one. 1+

Comment: @drewmore4 First off, stop worrying about performance. There won't be a significant difference and it's not even clear to me if inheritance will be faster than composition. To fix your design, make your ArrayList a private variable and create Library methods to do what you want. Users of your class shouldn't even know that there's an ArrayList inside of it. If your Library doesn't do anything except talk to the ArrayList, I'd advise not having a Library class at all (just use the ArrayList).

Answer (score 1):

You should do the loading *instead of* making a new instance of `Library`.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is to make `load` a `static` method thar returns a brand new instance:

```
class Library {
  static Library load(Stream in) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
public Library(){
    addAll(load());
}
```

As others have said, it isn't the best design practice to do this but perhaps you're doing something we don't know.

Comment: Yes, this certainly works. Given my edit above, do you think this approach makes sense?