# Change ENUM's value inside the ENUM class function using this in JAVA

Tags: java, oop, enums, syntax-error

I have a Java enum called entry. My goal is to have a function which changes the enum value to the other one. In case my enum value is X, I want it to become Y and vice versa. The code I tried to write is here. But this would not compile and it says variable expected in the place where I have used `this`.

```
public enum Entry {
    X,
    O;

    public void switchEntry(){
        this == Entry.X? this = Entry.O: Entry.X ;
    }
}
```

Also I want to know if it is possible without using an additional value variable inside my ENUM class.
Thank you. Apologies if it is a stupid question.

Comment: @Jens There are times when you might want to toggle between two values such as `BLACK` and `WHITE` like a chess board, or `ON` and `OFF` like an electrical switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change an enum to another enum. You can however update an enum **variable** to refer to another enum value.

```java
public enum Entry {
    X,
    O;

    public Entry switchEntry() {
        return (this == X ? O : X);
    }
}
```

```java
Entry e = Entry.X;

e = e.switchEntry();
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot switch the value of an enum itself. What you can do, is use the enum in a class and witch the value there:

```java
class Test {

    private Entry entry = Entry.X;

    public void switchEntry() {
        entry = entry == Entry.X ? Entry.O : Entry.X;
    }
}

enum Entry {
    X, O;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The major thing that stops you from doing this, is that `this` is `final`. You can't reassign `this`. [There are good reasons for this restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979623/why-is-assignment-to-this-not-allowed-in-java).

However, even if you could reassign `this`, your method doesn't make much sense, because there are only two instances of `Entry`, *ever* - `Entry.X` and `Entry.O`:

[§8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

> An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants. It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly instantiate an enum type

So if you did:

```
Entry.X.switchEntry();
```

You would not be able to access the object originally referenced by `Entry.X` from that point onwards! Because `switchEntry` sets `Entry.X` to `Entry.O`! Now both `Entry.X` and `Entry.O` refers to the same object!

And what about if I have a class that contains a `getEntry` method, that returns a private field `entry`, without a setter for `entry`. What if you called (and this is perfectly valid Java code):

```
getEntry().switchEntry();
```

Would that set my private `entry` variable? If so you've just broken encapsulation! Or would it do something stupid like `getEntry() = Entry.O;`?

Do you see the problem with allowing your implementation of `switchEntry`?

Anyway, you should instead write a method that *returns* an instance of `Entry`. You can then use `=` at the *call site* to assign to whatever you like.