# How to change the object of the class itself from inside itself?

Tags: java

How to change the object of the class itself from inside itself? I have one class like this:

```
public class AdvancedArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T>
```

And I want to assign a new object to itself. But, I am unable to do that. Just see this code:

```
AdvancedArrayList<T> abcd = this; // works fine
this = abcd; // ERROR: variable expected
```

[image]

And this is my entire class:

```
public class AdvancedArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public void reverse(){
        Collections.reverse(this);
    }

    public void removeDuplicates(){
        ArrayList<T> wordDuplicate = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<T> tempList= new ArrayList<>();


        for (T dupObject : wordDuplicate) {
            if (!tempList.contains(dupObject)) {
                tempList.add(dupObject);
            }
        }
        this = tempList;
    }
}
```

So, how can I change the object of the class itself?

Comment: You cannot. Why do you exactly want this?

Comment: Even if you could do what you've proposed, it would effectively be a no-op as you already did `abcd=this`, so the following `this=abcd` is equivalent to `this=this`. Also keep in mind the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: @Rogue actually no. I will edit the content in the list.

Comment: @MCEmperor i need it because i am adding a `removeDuplicates` method in the class. So, when the duplicates are filtered in a temp list, I want to assign it to the object

Comment: When you assign a list reference to another list variable, e.g. `List<T> something = abcd`, they are _the same object_. If you modify one, you modify the other. In all honesty, I would avoid inheritance for this solution.

Comment: But @Rogue, how can I update the list inside that object because it asks me for my custom class, not the list it extends to.

Comment: Why not copy the elements into the AdvancedArrayList? Am I missing something? It would be very helpful if you shared the whole `AdvancedArrayList()` class.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow your last comment. Can you update your question to include the relevant information surrounding what you're really doing? Also be wary of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) (a common pitfall for anyone).

Comment: @Sambhav.K You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979623/why-is-assignment-to-this-not-allowed-in-java

Comment: `ArrayList` is not meant to be inherited. If you want to write your own list collection, extend `AbstractList`. Your custom list can then use composition to delegate to its inner list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#removeDuplicates` method is attempting to mutate the list object it belongs to (known by `this`, within this class), and as such should actually make those modifications to the list itself (rather than a copy). Note as well, that by iterating your newly-made list `wordDuplicate`, the `for` loop will not actually execute (since there are no values inside the list). I would personally keep track using a `Set` (namely, `HashSet` with a roughly `O(1)` lookup, aka nearly constant-time), while taking advantage of the `Iterator#remove` method:

```
public void removeDuplicates() {
    Set<T> seen = new HashSet<>();
    Iterator<T> itr = this.iterator(); //similar to the mechanics behind for-each
    while (itr.hasNext()) { //while another element can be found
        T next = itr.next(); //get the next element
        if (!seen.add(next)) { //#add returns "true" only if it was not in the Set previously
            itr.remove(); //if it was previously in the set, remove it from the List
        }
    }
}
```

Note as well, that the semantics you are describing nicely fit the definition of a `Set`, which is a collection of items that do not contain duplicates. There are varients of `Set` (i.e. `LinkedHashSet`) which also allow linear traversal of the elements, based on insertion-order.

For a simpler, non-iterator solution, you could also do a "dirty swap" of the elements after your calculation, which would be similar to what you attempted to achieve via `this = list`:

```
public void removeDuplicates() {
    Set<T> seen = new LinkedHashSet<>(); //to preserve iteration order
    for (T obj : this) { //for each object in our current list
        seen.add(obj); //will only add non-duplicates!
    }
    this.clear(); //wipe out our old list
    this.addAll(seen); //add back our non-duplicated elements
}
```

This can be quicker to write, but would be less performant than the in-place removal (since the entire list must be wiped and added to again). Lastly, if this is a homework problem, try to avoid copy-pasting code directly, and instead write it out yourself at the very least. Merely working towards a solution can help to solidify the information down the line.

Comment: But, it could be optimised this way also: `Set<T> seen = new LinkedHashSet<>(this);
        this.clear();
        this.addAll(seen);`

Comment: This is true, but note that it would not really be "optimized" for the same reasons. It's shorter to write, but longer to run. I also purposefully avoided any compound statements in my answer so I could explain each step o/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in Java. `this` cannot be reassigned. Why (and when) do you need to re-assign an object from within itself?

When you have code such as `obj.replace(otherObj)` with an imaginary implementation of `void replace(Object other) { this = other; }`, then why not simply write `obj = otherObj` to update the reference?

---

Further clarifications after comments:

`ArrayList` is not meant to be inherited. If you want to write your own list collection, extend `AbstractList`. Your custom list can then use composition to delegate to its inner list.