# Test List<List<T>> contains the same items in any order

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I want to compare two `List<List<String>>` that contain the same elements in any order. They are not equal.

```
// expectedResult 
[
  ["ate","eat","tea"],
  ["nat","tan"],
  ["bat"]
]
```

the other is

```
// result
[
  ["eat", "tea", "ate"], 
  ["bat"], 
  ["tan", "nat"]
]
```

**What test methods (from which libraries) should I use to compare elements inside **elements** without sorting ?**

I tried this unsuccessfully.

```
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

assertThat(expectedResult, containsInAnyOrder(result));
```

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483541/deep-compare-sets-in-java

Comment: Is order of list of lists are same (not the items in a list)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `.containsAll()` works for a Collection not for a Collection of Collection.

Basically I ended up comparing each elements of the first collection, then use `.containsAll()` for the nested collection.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

    @Test
    public void groupAnagramsTest() {
        List<List<String>> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("bat"), Arrays.asList("nat", "tan"), Arrays.asList("ate", "eat", "tea"));
        List<List<String>> result = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("bat"), Arrays.asList("tan", "nat"), Arrays.asList("tea", "eat", "ate"));

        // to test the equality without order, 
        // assert that all elements are contained in the compared list and vice versa
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            Assert.assertTrue(expectedResult.get(i).containsAll(result.get(i)));
            Assert.assertTrue(result.get(i).containsAll(expectedResult.get(i)));
        }
    }
```

**NOTE: the order of the outer List is the same between the two. Otherwise it won't work.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use **[Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)**

> [public static boolean isEqualCollection(Collection a, Collection b)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEqualCollection-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-)
>
> Returns true iff the given Collections contain exactly the same elements with exactly the same cardinalities.
>
> That is, iff the cardinality of e in a is equal to the cardinality of e in b, for each element e in a or b.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - a - the first collection, must not be null
> - b - the second collection, must not be null
>
> Returns: **true** iff the collections contain the same elements with the same cardinalities.

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestSO {

    @Test
    public void testLists() {
        List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("ate", "eat", "tea"), Arrays.asList("nat", "tan"), Arrays.asList("bat"));
        List<List<String>> sameList = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("ate", "eat", "tea"), Arrays.asList("bat"), Arrays.asList("nat", "tan"));
        List<List<String>> differentList = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("ate", "eat"), Arrays.asList("bat"), Arrays.asList("nat", "tan"));

        Assert.assertTrue(CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(list, sameList));
        Assert.assertFalse(CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(list, differentList));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. The inner list are still in the same order.  Try to re-order `{"ate", "eat", "tea"}` -> `{"tea","ate", "eat"}` in `list` , you'll notice an error

Answer (score 0):

To compare two `List<List<String>>` in any order and any order in the inner list (except missing or duplicated elements) basically to compare their anagrams:

```
List<List<String>> actual = List<List<String>> expected = List.of(
        List.of("bat"),
        List.of("tea", "ate", "eat"),
        List.of("tan", "nat")
);
List<List<String>> expected = List.of(
        List.of("nat", "tan"),
        List.of("bat"),
        List.of("ate", "eat", "tea")
);

Set<Integer> actualHash = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> expectedHash = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < actual.size(); i++) {
    actualHash.add(new HashSet<>(actual.get(i)).hashCode());
    expectedHash.add(new HashSet<>(expected.get(i)).hashCode());
}
Assertions.assertThat(actualHash).hasSameHashCodeAs(expectedHash);
```

I used `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions` here, but it can be any Assert.